# Cut the output of my FILENAME variable with awk?

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk

I have this script :

```
for fn in /var/www/cgi-bin/LPAR_MAP/*; do awk -F',|;' 'NR==1 { print "FILENAME ========================== : " FILENAME }
/'$test'/ { 

print ""
print "LPARS :" $2

print "RAM : " $5

print "CPU 1 : " $6

print "CPU 2 : " $7

print "" 
print ""}' $fn; done
```

This script allow me to display informations from CSV like this :

```
FRAME : MIAIBYA00 
------------------

FILENAME ========================== : /var/www/cgi-bin/LPAR_MAP/PowerSys-LPARProcPool-20180705.csv

LPARS :miavioya01-not-work
RAM : 
CPU 1 : 
CPU 2 : 


FILENAME ========================== : /var/www/cgi-bin/LPAR_MAP/PowerSys-LPARmap-20180122.csv

LPARS :miaibc05
RAM : 40
CPU 1 : null
CPU 2 : 2



LPARS :miaiba05
RAM : 18
CPU 1 : null
CPU 2 : 2
```

The filename output is :

```
FILENAME ========================== : /var/www/cgi-bin/LPAR_MAP/PowerSys-LPARmap-20180122.csv
```

But I want to keep only the date :

```
FILENAME ========================== : 20180122
```

I'm able to do this in a terminal with this command :

```
echo FILENAME ========================== : /var/www/cgi-bin/LPAR_MAP/PowerSys-LPARmap-20180122.csv | cut -d '-' -f4 | cut -d'.' -f1
```

But I don't know how to do this in my script... Can you show me how ?

Comment: cut equivalent in awk: `split("-", arr, FILENAME); split(".",a2,arr[3]); print a2[0];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
{ print "FILENAME ========================== : " FILENAME }
```

To

```
{ split(FILENAME,a,"[-.]");print "FILENAME ========================== : " a[4] }
```

It will split the `FILENAME` by `-` and `.`  and store it in array `a`.  Then date should be the fort block in array `a`, `a[4]`.

```
{split($0,a,"[-.]");t=substr(a[4],1,4)"-"substr(a[4],5,2)"-"substr(a[4],7);print t}
2018-01-22
```

Comment: That works great ! Last question, if I want to change 20180122 to 2018-01-22, how can I do this ?

Comment: @Makmy look at the command `substr`.  See updated post. https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following code:

```
for fn in /home/bodia/affdex-sdk/docs/*; do awk -F',|;' 'function basename(file, a, n) {
    n = split(file, a, "/")
    split(a[n], a, ".")
    return a[1]
  }
 NR==1 { print "FILENAME ========================== : " basename(FILENAME) }
/'$test'/ { 

print ""
print "LPARS :" $2

print "RAM : " $5

print "CPU 1 : " $6

print "CPU 2 : " $7

print "" 
print ""}' $fn; done
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to provide multiple Field Separators, e.g. `-F[-]"|"[.]` which will isolate your number as `$(NF-1)`. For example:

```
awk -F[-]"|"[.] '{ print $(NF-1) }'
```

Results in output of:

```
20180122
```

Run on the full-file you would want to match against `"FILENAME"` at the beginning of the line, e.g.

```
awk -F[-]"|"[.] '/^FILENAME/{ print $(NF-1) }'
```